Make text in textinput be the same as in label
I placing textinput and label with same settings of text in same place but text isnt same.
I am trying to make selection for label by addding label and putting textinput over it and making it transparent. Also i am limiting label width. I tried to adjust textinput size to texture size of label text, but that didnt help. I expected that texts from textinput and label would be in same place so textinput selection would be accurate around label's text.
Result:

Code:

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class main(App):

    def build(self):


        f = FloatLayout()




        # def changesmth(i):
        #     i._label.refresh()
        #     x,y = i._label.texture.size
        #     textinput2.size = (x,y)
        #     xp, yp = i.pos
        #     textinput2.pos=(xp-50,yp-10)
        #     textinput2.line_spacing = 5




        label = Label(text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",text_size = (400, None) ,markup=True,font_size="24", size=(400, 100),pos=(100,100), size_hint=(None, None))
        textinput2 = TextInput(text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", font_size="24",size=(400,100),pos=(100,100), size_hint=(None, None), readonly=True, foreground_color= (1,1,1,0.5), background_color = (1,0,0,0.1))


        #changesmth(label)

        f.add_widget(textinput2)
        f.add_widget(label)




        return f





main().run()

Please answer without using .kv language. Thanks.

Just a few properties need to be set. Try changing:
    label = Label(text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",text_size = (400, None) ,markup=True,font_size="24", size=(400, 100),pos=(100,100), size_hint=(None, None))
    textinput2 = TextInput(text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", font_size="24",size=(400,100),pos=(100,100), size_hint=(None, None), readonly=True, foreground_color= (1,1,1,0.5), background_color = (1,0,0,0.1))

to:
    label = Label(text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",text_size = (400, 100), markup=True,
                  font_size="24", size=(400, 100),pos=(100,100), size_hint=(None, None), valign='top')
    textinput2 = TextInput(text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", font_size="24",size=(400,100),
                           pos=(100,100), size_hint=(None, None), readonly=True, foreground_color= (1,1,1,0.5),
                           background_color = (1,0,0,0.1), padding=0)

The key changes are the text_size and valign settings of the Label and the padding setting of the TextInput.

Thanks for answer, i redacted code to my needs and now i have another problem, i cant paste this long code so its here https://pastebin.com/bZpRjfTd, firstly all is good but then text in textinput makes strange indent and all text then goes wrong

If you have another question you should do a new post for it.
